# Проблемы с созданием объекта списка собственного класса Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, классы, list, объекты

По идее должен создаваться объект списка собственного класса, в который будут добавлены элементы (любого типа данных) в размере 20 штук (значение может быть любым). После чего на консоль требуется вывести результат вывода 23 элементов (от 0 до 22)
Удалось создать объект класса `Mylist`.

Не понимаю как создать объект списка собственного класса

Ниже представлен код программы :

```
class MyList<T> {
    private val list: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()

    fun getAt(index: Int): T? {
        return if (index < list.size) {
            list[index]
        } else {
            throw MyException("Ошибка получения элемента по индексу $index")
        }
    }

    fun add(elemet: T) {
        list.add(elemet)
    }

    class MyException(message: String) : Exception(message)
}



fun main (args: Array<String>) {
    val myList = MyList<Int>()
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема действительно не ясна. Возможно, вы имеете в виду, что вам непонятно, что надо запустить (видимо) цикл, в котором можно наполнить ваш список данными и потом по этому списку проитерироваться?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, именно это и имею ввиду

Comment: Наверное вам что-то такое надо: `(0..19).forEach {.myList.add(it) } (0..22).forEach {.println(myList.get(it)) }`

Comment: Проблема решилась  fun main(array: Array<String>){
val list = MyList<Int>()
    for (i in 0..20){
        list.add(2)
    }
    for ( i in 0..22){
        println("Индекс $1 равен ${list.getAt(i)}")
    }
}